# How to make two 'join' statements when printing a list, if one involves a 'for' loop

Tags: python

I'm very new to Python and coding in general (started an introductory course at uni about 2-3 weeks ago). The assignment question that I'm struggling with is as follows:

"A year is a leap year if it is divisible by four, except that any year divisible by 100 is a leap year only if it is also divisible by 400. Write a program which works out the leap years between two years given by the user. The program should list 10 leap years per line, with commas between each year listed and a full stop at the end."

I have got most of the way there, I'm just struggling with the last sentence. I've figured out how to print 10 numbers per line using a for loop, and I also know how to add commas/a full stop in the relevant places, but I can't work out how to combine these statements together to print just a single list. Forgive me if I'm making a rookie error - I am, after all, very much a rookie! My code is as follows (the print statements at the end being the parts that I wish to combine together):

```
def main():
st_year = int(input("Enter start year: "))
end_year = int(input("Enter end year: "))

lyears = []

print("Here is a list of leap years between {} and {}:".format(st_year, end_year))
for y in range(st_year, end_year+1):
  no_leap = 0
  leap = y
if (y % 4 == 0 and y % 100 != 0) or (y % 4 == 0 and y % 100 == 0 and y % 400 == 0):
  y = leap
  lyears.append(y)
else:
  y = no_leap

print(", ".join(str(i) for i in lyears) + ".")
for i in range(0, len(lyears), 10):
  print(" ".join(str(j) for j in lyears[i:i+10]))

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

This produces the output (between the years 1000 and 1200):

```
1004, 1008, 1012, 1016, 1020, 1024, 1028, 1032, 1036, 1040, 1044, 1048, 
1052, 1056, 1060, 1064, 1068, 1072, 1076, 1080, 1084, 1088, 1092, 1096, 
1104, 1108, 1112, 1116, 1120, 1124, 1128, 1132, 1136, 1140, 1144,
1148, 1152, 1156, 1160, 1164, 1168, 1172, 1176, 1180, 1184, 1188, 1192, 
1196, 1200.
1004 1008 1012 1016 1020 1024 1028 1032 1036 1040
1044 1048 1052 1056 1060 1064 1068 1072 1076 1080
1084 1088 1092 1096 1104 1108 1112 1116 1120 1124
1128 1132 1136 1140 1144 1148 1152 1156 1160 1164
1168 1172 1176 1180 1184 1188 1192 1196 1200
```

Sorry for the long post, would highly appreciate it if anyone can point me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

So the issue is the last phrase that you have to display. Unfortunately, you can't use the usual part of the loop, right?

```
for i in range(0, len(lyears), 10):
    print(",".join(str(j) for j in lyears[i:i+10]))
```

Would work, except for the last line, but it's a start. Now, you have to do some trick.

```
almost_last = (len(years) - 1 ) // 10
for i in range(almost_last):
    print(",".join(str(j) for j in lyears[i*10:(i+1)*10]))
print(",".join(str(j) for j in lyears[almost_last*10:(almost_last+1)*10]) + ".")
```

Comment: Hi Matthieu, thanks for the help! When I trialled the second piece of code you gave, it seems to print the full stop quite a large number of lines below the numbers?

Comment: Oops, I deleted a `// 10` by mistake, sorry.

Comment: Again, thank you! This works well. I have just a couple of small questions, if you don't mind answering? Firstly, would it be possible to give a very brief overview of how exactly the code works? And secondly (this is a problem with my original code), I notice that it does not print any commas after the numbers at the end of the lines (excluding the last row of course, which ends in the full stop), so could I potentially make this edit by doing something similar to the final print command? Thank you so much, you've been an enormous help!

Comment: Oh, you need also the "," at the end of the intermediate lines? So yes, just add a `+","`, it will be enough. So the idea of the code is that the last line must not be processed with the `for` loop. And you need at least one element in that last loop, so that's the `len() - 1`. Then, I just divide the result by `10` to get the number of iterations I need, and then I do the last iteration by hand to change the last character. I could also have used a function that would have taken `years`, `i` and the last character as a parameter to factor the specific string out.

Comment: @Jamkind If this answer solved your problem, [please consider accepting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)